# How to wait a little time before screen capture?

Tags: excel, vba, automation, screen-capture, pause

So I have the below code which clicks a button and then captures the screen. But the issue is that it captures what the screen was before I click the button because it all happens so quickly in VBA. So I put an `Application.Wait` statement before it captured the screen, but it did not help and the same exact thing happened. If I put the `Application.Wait` statement before the `Call keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, 0, 0)` then for some reason it copies and pastes the actual code instead of the capture of the screen which is weird. Therefore I am wondering how I can wait so that it captures the screen after it has a chance to load. I have only included the important code. I am working with two screens (monitors) so I am interacting with a web page on the other screen.

```
Sub getTest()
    Dim CurrentPosition As POINTAPI

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    Call GetCursorPos(CurrentPosition)
    Call mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    Call mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)

    Call CopyScreen
End Sub

Sub CopyScreen()
    Call keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, 0, 0)

    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="TBD"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: I’d look into using selenium basic if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try calling a generic "**Pause**" procedure such as:

```
Sub Pause(seconds As Single)
    Dim tmr As Single
    tmr = Timer
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until Timer > (seconds + tmr)
End Sub
```

---

(...or the same thing but in the more "compressed" fashion that I usually use it:)

```
Sub Pause(sec As Single)
    Dim t As Single: t = Timer: Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Timer > (sec + t)
End Sub
```

---

Call the procedure simply like:

```
Pause 5
```

...for a five second pause **while still allowing system events to take place**.

Unfortunately, you're going to have plenty of headaches trying to use mouse/keyboard events to control an application like this.  You might want to consider using a separate application that is better suited to automation.  Or, perhaps you can find an alternate way to get your image, depending on which application it's in.

---

### More Information:

- Microsoft Docs: [**DoEvents function (VBA)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function)

Comment: Also, you'll probably need to pause *after* the screenshot, before pasting, maybe for a half second or so to allow the data to buffer onto the clipboard.  Does this software have no built-in screen capturing functionality -- and wouldn't the actual text be better than an image of it? (Maybe try a Google search for "bloomberg browser scrape")... Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with IE and aiming to capture that screen/window?

You probably need to wait until the page has finished loading. Waiting a period of time isn't a guarantee it has finished loading.

This is what I have used in the past to load a page and make sure it is finished before moving to the next step in my code (granted I've never been looking to take a screenshot).

```
    With IE
        .visible = true
        .Navigate URL
        Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
        Do Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
    End With
```

I hope this helps.

Josh

Comment: Hi, I am actually using a software called Bloomberg. Not IE. But this question does not require any knowledge of Bloomberg. @Josh

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Application.OnTime` event, to invoke the function after 5 sec:

```
Sub getTest()
    ' ...
    Call Application.OnTime (Now + TimeValue("00:00:5"), "CopyScreen")
End Sub
```